# Wait for event before continue processing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Currently I have problem like below.

I create a function for handling retrying.

```
function retry(fn, maxTimes) {
  const attempt = async (time) => {
    try {
      const result = fn()
      return (result && result.then) ? await result : result
    }
    catch (err) {
      if (time === maxTimes) throw err
      return await attempt(++time)
    }
  }

  return attempt()
}
```

And I have another method like

```
_handleData(data) {
  throw new Error('this is error')
}

const data = ''
const start = () => {
  this.item.on('data', ::this._handleData)
  this.item.write(data) // trigger event data
}
try {
  await retry(start, MAX_RETRY_TIMES)
}
catch (err) {
  console.log('error', err)
}
```

But function `start` doesn't do retry. Does any way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Share more code, not clear if `data` event is ever triggered

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly this.item.write(data) this command trigger event data above

Comment: That whole `return (result && result.then) ? await result : result` should be just `return result`.

Comment: Your `start` function does not return a promise, and it won't get rejected on a `data` event. You will need to promisify `this.item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by this way

```
startApp() {
  const data = ''
  const start = () => {
    try {
      const sendData = await this._sendData(data)
      this._handleData(sendData)
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw err
    }
  }
  try {
    await retry(start, MAX_RETRY_TIMES)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err)
  }
}

_sendData(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.item.on('data', resolve)
    this.item.write(data) // trigger event data
  })
}

_handleData(data) {
  throw new Error('this is error')
}
```